# Q. Accept two numbers using an InputBox in two different variables and print the sum of two in a message box. (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net

I have to answer this in Visual Basic.I actually don't have any idea how to solve this, our teacher barely teaches us practical stuff. I have to submit this assignment by today too.

I have tried to do solve it and searched the internet for it, but I could barely understand it.

Comment: Does [Lesson 12 : MsgBox and InputBox](https://www.vbtutor.net/vb2012/vb2012_lesson12.html) help at all? Or maybe [Visual Basic Functions: The Input Box](https://www.functionx.com/vb/functions/inputbox.htm)? Both found by goggling for "vb.net inputbox example".

Comment: Accept two numbers using ONE InputBox, or two numbers calling InputBox two different times?

Comment: Also, what kind of application is this? Console, WinForm, WPF, etc...? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using [Integer.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-int32-tryparse(system-string-system-int32@)):

```
Dim value1, value2 As Integer
Dim response As String = InputBox("Enter first Integer:")
If Integer.TryParse(response, value1) Then
    response = InputBox("Enter second Integer:")
    If Integer.TryParse(response, value2) Then
        Dim sum As Integer = value1 + value2
        MessageBox.Show("The sum of " & value1 & " and " & value2 & " is " & sum)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(response & " is not a valid Integer!")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show(response & " is not a valid Integer!")
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code you can build upon:

```
Public Sub AddTwoNumbers()
     Dim FirstNumber As String = Convert.toInt32(InputBox("Enter the first number.")) 'Get the first number
     Dim SecondNumber As String = Convert.toInt32InputBox("Enter the second number.")) 'Get the second number
     Dim Result As Integer = 0 'Used to store the result in
     'Now perform the calculation.
     Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber
     'Then show the result in a MessageBox
     MessageBox.Show("The result is: " & Result.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: And now it will crash and burn when the user types in something within the InputBox that is not an Integer, like `integers are silly!`. How about showing an example with [Integer.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-int32-tryparse(system-string-system-int32@)) instead?...

Comment: I know that I did not do everything, I said that they would have to build upon it.